# Does the && (logical AND) operator have a higher precedence than || (logical OR) operator in Java?

Tags: java, operator-precedence, control-flow, boolean-operations, short-circuiting

From my previous knowledge the (logical AND) has a higher precedence than the (logical OR), so for example in the following line of Java code `boolExp2` will be compared with `boolExp3` before comparing `boolExp1` with `boolExp2`:

```
boolean b = boolExp1 || boolExp2 && boolExp3
```

Which is the same as:

```
boolean b = boolExp1 || (boolExp2 && boolExp3)
```

But in the following example I don't see this as true, in the following code I have an int variable `x` which is equal to 1, when the code increments `x`, which is in this line of the code:

```
boolean b = (1<2) || (6<x++) || (++x>9) && (true^false) ^ (x++<7);
```

After this line is executed the value of the variable `x` does not change, does this relate to the 'Short Circuit' in the code, I am not an expert in this field, or is there something else?

**Full java code:**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int x = 1;
        boolean b = (1<2) || (6<x++) || (++x>9) && (true^false) ^ (x++<7);
        
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println("x = "+ x);
    }

}
```

**The output:**

```
true
x = 1
```

**Expectation:**

```
true
x = 4
```

Please provide a detailed execution of the code.

Comment: "Although AND takes precedence over OR in many languages, this is not a universal property of short-circuit evaluation." [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation#Precedence)

Comment: the expression will be interpreted as `(1<2) || ( (6<x++) || ( (++x>9) && ((true^false) ^ (x++<7)) ) )`, the result of it is the result of evaluating the first `||`. From the [JLS 15.24](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se22/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24): "the left-hand operand expression is evaluated first; ... If the resulting value is true, the value of the conditional-or expression is true and the right-hand operand expression is not evaluated." || Maybe comparing to addition/multiplication can help - e.g. `1 + 2 * 3` is evaluated as `1 + (2 * 3)`